# Разбор предложения по членам. Помогите найти ошибки

Tags: синтаксис, обстоятельство

Правильно ли разобран текст? И является ли инф. "собирать" из 2 предл. обстоятельством цели? Из темноты сверкнуло созвездие огней, и вода под этими огнями заметалась острыми быстрыми вспышками. Оленька пошла в лес  собирать грибы. Долго бродила она по лесу, болоту в березняках. В ольховых зарослях ручьев и в низинах появились первые стайки зарянок и запели свои несложные песенки. Под пеньком в хвое и листьях шныряют муравьи, букашки, личинки. Звонко поют птицы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно. Собирать - обстоятельство цели: пошла (зачем?)собирать.

Можно добавить ещё вторые роли членов предложения:

созвездие (чего? какое?) огней, зарослях (каких? чего?) ручьев, стайки (какие? кого?) зарянок - дополнения и несогласованные определения, шныряют (где? в чём?) в хвое и листьях - обстоятельства и дополнения.